# Umbraco gallery create partial

Tags: razor, umbraco

I have a Frontpagr page as root item and under this i have a gallery as a media picker.

i want to use the images from my media picker in my master template which is around my Frontpage.

i have tried anything i've seen online...

Can anyone help me here?

STRUCTURE:

```
<master template> (Using Gallery from frontpage)
Frontpage(Gallery)
  about us
  contact 
  calendar
<master template
```

i have tried to create partials and trying to render out ipublished content but none of them worked

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do in your Master template, is:

```
var galleryItems = Model.Content.Site().GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("gallery")
```

Where "gallery" is the alias of the gallery media picker.

You can then iterate over your collection of gallery items like so:

```
var galleryItems = Model.Content.Site().GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("gallery");
foreach (var image in galleryItems)
{
    <img src="@image.Url" />
}
```

If you want to put it all together inside of a partial view, simply create a partial view in Views/Partials and e.g. name it "FrontpageGalleryItems.cshtml" and have it contain the same code.

On your Master template, you simply call the following code:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/FrontpageGalleryItems.cshtml")
```

Comment: If it works for you @AndersBootsmannLarsen - please make sure to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Yes i will :) thanks again and you may also upvote the question as a good question if you want to